# Set Fontawesome icon in ExtJS table column

Tags: extjs, font-awesome

How can I use fontawesome with ExtJS. I want to display an icon in table column.

For example I have this:

```
widget2: {
    viewTemplate: {
        title: 'Today\'s calls',
        closable: false,
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            width: '100%',
            columns: 2
        },
        items: [
            { html: '<i class="fas fa-home"></i>' },
            { html: '1,2' },
            { html: '1,3' },
            { html: '2,2' },
            { html: '3,2' },
            { html: '3,3' }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it shows me only this:

[image]

However in my main menu I have menu items with `iconCls: 'fa fa-home'` and it works. Tried to put that in table but it didn't work though.

Any help?

BTW I use ExtJS 6.

Comment: `fas` is the class name according to FontAwesome - https://fontawesome.com/icons/home?style=solid

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/font_ext.html) is some information about font awesome icons that sencha ExtJS 6 supports.

> Ext JS 6+ supports Font Awesome version 4.4.0. For a list of all
> available Font Awesome icons, please check out the [Font Awesome Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet).

Font awesome icons in Sencha need to start with 'x-fa' class, example:

```
iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home'
```

or

```
<span class="x-fa fa-home"></span>
```

This is a [list of all fa icons from version 4.4](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icons/) (see chapter 'Web Application Icons'). If you click on icon, you can see its class.

Hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Create one class in css for defining `font-family` and pass it to every html component you'll decide to make icon out of: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m5o)